# Finding the Current in a Series RLC Circuit

Tags: current

**Question :**

If the input to an RLC serise circuit is \$V=V_{in}\cos(wt)\$, what is the current I in the circuit in terms of \$V_{in}, w, t,R,L,C,\theta\$?

**Answer :**

$$I = \frac{V_{in}\cos(wt-\theta)}{\sqrt{R^2+(wL-1/wC)^2}}$$

---

**My Steps :**
\begin{align}
Z&=R+\frac{-j}{wC}+jwL\\
 &=\frac{RwC+j(w^2LC-1)}{wC}
\end{align}

If I sub the Z into \$I=\frac{V}{Z}\$ to gain \$Z^{-1}\$, the result seems wrong. How to obtain the answer?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to think about how theta got to be in the top equation for a little hint. Maybe they tell you what theta equals?

Comment: Hint:  the impedance \$Z\$ is the ratio of the voltage and current *phasors*.

Comment: Note also that you do not make any reference to the expression for the phase angle.

Answer (score 2):

The input voltage is $$V= V_{in}\cos(w t) = V_{in}\angle 0^{\circ}$$
The impedance is 
$$Z=R+\frac{-j}{wC}+jwL=R+j(wL-1/wC) = |Z|\angle\theta$$
Where \$|Z|=\sqrt{R^2+(wL-1/wC)^2}\$ and \$\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{wL-1/wC}{R}\right)\$.

Then the current will be 
$$I=\frac{V}{Z}=\frac{V_{in}\angle0^{\circ}}{|Z|\angle \theta}=\frac{V_{in}\angle(-\theta)}{|Z|}$$
$$=\frac{V_{in}\cos(wt-\theta)}{\sqrt{R^2+(wL-1/wC)^2}}$$